# Como fazer paginação em uma tabela que esta relacionada Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5.3

Existe **2 tabelas** e uma `pivot` onde ela faz a relação `ManyToMany` entre as **2 tabelas**.

Uma tabela se chama `Postagems` e a outra tabela se chama `Departamentos`, então estou tentando fazer uma busca relacionada por departamento, quando faço a busca ele pega os dados dos departamentos com os artigos da tabela postagem e retorna para mim, ficando assim minha busca.

***Veja:***

```
public function searchDepartamentoGet($id)
{
    $data = array(
        'titulo'        =>  'Artigo Por Departamento',
        'departamento'  =>  Departamento::with('postagems')
                                       ->where('id',  $id)
                                       ->paginate($this->departamento)
    );

    return view('frontend.artigo.departamentos' , $data);
}
```

Então essa busca me retorna esse resultado:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é que minha paginação somente faz a paginação na variável `departamento` que na verdade quero que ele faça a paginação na tabela relacionada `postagems` onde existem *3 artigos*.

Como poderia fazer essa paginação?

Comment: Natan se tem que fazer a pesquisa de `Postagems` então e fazer um filtro pelo que eu pude entender, tem como você postar as duas classes?

Comment: Achei uma forma bem tranquila de se fazer paginação com as tabelas relacionadas. Veja  Virgilio
 'departamento'  =>  Departamento::find($id)->postagems()->paginate($this->departamento)
Agora resolvi o problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem achei uma forma mais fácil de fazer uma paginação com tabelas relacionadas.Veja:

```
 'departamento'  =>  Departamento::find($id)->postagems()->paginate($this->departamento)
```

somente isso ai resolve o problema.

Comment: o que é `$this->departamento`????

Comment: É uma variável private onde contem o numero de paginas que ira aparecer na View
Ex quero que aparece 10 pagina na paginação 1
então eu crio um private $departamento = 10;
ai no método paginate(eu chamo a quant de paginaçao que eu quero $this->departamento). Ou vc pode somente fazer pagante(10) que da na mesma